# Dynamically setting attributes of ftp:inbound-channel-adapter using java code

Tags: java, ftp, spring-integration

Is any chance to change/set value of some of attributes from inbound-channel-adapter inside java code? 
I need to download specific file from ftp server. I don't know which file before running application so I have to set `filename-pattern` dynamically.
I've found one question about this but without correct answer so I ask again.
This is my `inbound-channel-adapter` configuration:

```
    <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter local-directory="ftp" 
            channel="getFtpChannel" 
            session-factory="ftpClientFactory" 
            charset="UTF-8"
            remote-directory="${remote-download-directory}"
            remote-file-separator="/"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            filename-pattern="">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="10000"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

And I want to set/change `filename-pattern`.
And here's my code which receives files according to this attribute but only if I set it in my configuration:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
        new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/src/citrus/resources/citrus-context.xml");
PollableChannel channel = 
        context.getBean("getFtpChannel", PollableChannel.class);
channel.receive();
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    fail(e.getMessage());
}
context.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't change `filename-pattern` at runtime, because that option is populated to the `FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter` `final` `path`.

However you can implement your own `FileListFilter<?>` and inject it to the `filter` option of the `<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

Since your `FileListFilter<?>` will be a bean you can simply get it from the context and call its `setPattern()`.

**UPDATE**

Something like this:

```
public class MyFtpPatterFileListFilter extends AbstractFileListFilter<FTPFile> {

    private final AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();

    private volatile String pattern;

    public void setPattern(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean accept(FTPFile file) {
        return !StringUtils.hasText(this.pattern) || this.matcher.match(this.pattern, this.getFilename(file));
    }

    private String getFilename(FTPFile file) {
        return (file != null) ? file.getName() : null;
    }

}
```

Usage

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter filter="myFtpFilter">
```

And modification:

```
MyFtpPatterFileListFilter filter = context.getBean("myFtpFilter", MyFtpPatterFileListFilter.class);

filter.setPattern("*.txt");
```

Comment: I know that I'm asking for a lot but could you give me some hint how can I do that? I have to implement `boolean accept()`. I should pass `Message<?>` object to this method? and (if yes) how can I get access to it's pattern?

Comment: Added some potential implementation.